# Can I recover bitcoins from an Armory wallet.lmdb file?

Tags: wallet, armory

I did a super deep disk clean to see if I could recover the wallet file but I was unable to find it. Only file I was able to find that is `armory_*****_wallet.lmdb`. Does this file have any connection with the original wallet (`.wallet`) file itself?

If yes, is it possible to rescue the wallet from it?

Comment: See https://www.reddit.com/r/Bitcoin/comments/kozavy/bitcoin_armory_does_armorys_lmdb_file_contains/

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick I just asked the question over there as well in detail , should I delete the one in here?

Comment: You could post an answer here as well when/if you solve the problem. But, in my view,  it's OK to delete the question here if you want.

Comment: I feel like this problem is not solveble :-( I was just hoping maybe ` lmdb` file might contain the private-key. I just tried my chance to reach out someone who is capable of helping out but seems like I have no hope

Comment: I've no idea but it seems to me there's a chance the private keys are in the Lightning Memory-Mapped DataBase (LMDB) file. Probably encrypted using the wallet password.

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick I am able to find the encryption/wallet password. Which encryption algorithms could I try to decrypt it, or is there any standard procedure to decrypt it?

Comment: I don't know, maybe search source code in https://github.com/goatpig/BitcoinArmory ?

Comment: In `PyBtcWallet.py` file I have found a comment as `I have ONLY implemented deterministic wallets, using ECDSA Diffie-Hellman shared-secret crypto operations.` but I am not certain that's the used one